# How to identify item and click on x,y area for game

Tags: pyautogui

[Order #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJxld.jpg)[Order #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihm5A.jpg)

(Yes, it's Roblox)
I am currently trying to figure out how to make a code which sees the order of a customer and clicks on the respective item. It doesn't seem too bad but my issue is when the number of customer items differ. I also want to figure out how to make it so that the program knows when the code is done and to press 'Done'. What would be the best way to do this?

I thought I could add an auto clicker but that would not work as I don't know how to make the program know the order and so on.